# Handling touch events, check if one is holding a button

Tags: lua, coronasdk

i have made my own script for this but, it doesnt want to work properly:

1. when you don't touch right at the image, it doesnt react.
2. If you touch properly but move a little, then it is laggy, and the shooting button doesn't work.

I would be so happy if it worked like this:

1. When touching at or little around button then rotate my ship. **DONE**
2. When you move your finger a little then still rotate the ship. **DONE**
3. If you just tap, then rotate a little. **DONE**
4. If you are holding your finger on the button then rotate by 5° and after a little longer about 8°. **DONE**
5. Now, while i am touching one of the dpads, and touch the shooting button, it stops rotating. That needs to be fixed and i dont know how. I need to be able shoot while im rotating.

Well so here is what i tried with my code.

```
local isPressed = false
local tmr_holdFlight
local touchedXTimes = 0

function holdingLeft()
    if isPressed == true then
        if rotationOfship > 0 then
            if touchedXTimes < 10 then
                rotationOfship = rotationOfship-2
                touchedXTimes = touchedXTimes + 1
                ship.rotation = rotationOfship
            elseif touchedXTimes > 9 then 
                rotationOfship = rotationOfship-5
                touchedXTimes = touchedXTimes + 1
                ship.rotation = rotationOfship  
            elseif touchedXTimes > 29 then
                rotationOfship = rotationOfship-8
                touchedXTimes = touchedXTimes + 1
                ship.rotation = rotationOfship                                       
            end 
            print(touchedXTimes)
        else 
            rotationOfship = 360
        end
    elseif isPressed == false then 
        timer.cancel(tmr_hold)
        isPressed = false
    end
end

function holdingRight()
    if isPressed == true then
        if rotationOfship < 360 then
            if touchedXTimes < 10 then
                rotationOfship = rotationOfship+2
                touchedXTimes = touchedXTimes + 1
                ship.rotation = rotationOfship
            elseif touchedXTimes > 9 then 
                rotationOfship = rotationOfship+5
                touchedXTimes = touchedXTimes + 1
                ship.rotation = rotationOfship  
            elseif touchedXTimes > 29 then
                rotationOfship = rotationOfship+8
                touchedXTimes = touchedXTimes + 1
                ship.rotation = rotationOfship                                       
            end 
            print(touchedXTimes)
        else 
            rotationOfship = 0
        end
    elseif isPressed == false then 
        timer.cancel(tmr_hold)
    end
end

function onDpadLeftTouch(event)
    -- body
    if event.phase=='began' then
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(event.target)
    end

     if event.phase=='began' then
        isPressed = true
        if tmr_hold ~= nil then timer.cancel(tmr_hold) end
        tmr_hold = timer.performWithDelay( 8, holdingLeft, 0)
    elseif event.phase == "ended" then
        isPressed = false
        timer.cancel(tmr_hold)
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(nil)
        touchedXTimes = 0
    end
end

function onDpadRightTouch(event)
    -- body
    if event.phase=='began' then
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(event.target)
    end

    if event.phase=='began' then
        isPressed = true
        if tmr_hold ~= nil then timer.cancel(tmr_hold) end
        tmr_hold = timer.performWithDelay( 8, holdingRight, 0)
    elseif event.phase=='ended' then
        isPressed = false
        timer.cancel(tmr_hold)
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(nil)
        touchedXTimes = 0
    end
end

local function pointAtDistance(angle, distance)
    -- Convert angle to radians as lua math functions expect radians
    local r = math.rad(angle)
    local x = math.cos(r) * distance
    local y = math.sin(r) * distance    
    return x, y
end

local isShooting = false

function resetShooting()
    isShooting = false
end

function onLaserButtonTouch(event)
    if event.phase == "began" and isShooting == false then
        isShooting = true

        bullet = display.newImageRect("images/laser.png",math.random(5,20),5/2)
            bullet.x = halfW
            bullet.y = halfH                
            bullet.name = "bullet"
            bullet.rotation = rotationOfship-90
            physics.addBody( bullet, "dynamic", { isSensor=true, radius=10} )
            group:insert(bullet)

        ship:toFront()

        audio.play( laserSound, { channel=2, loops=0}  )

        local newX, newY = pointAtDistance(rotationOfship-90, 400)

        bullet:setLinearVelocity( newX/2, newY/2 )

        tmr_shoot = timer.performWithDelay( math.random(300,400), resetShooting, 1)
    elseif event.phase=='ended' then

    end     
end

dpad_left = display.newImageRect("images/dpad/left.png", 78/2, 78/2)
    dpad_left.x = 50
    dpad_left.y = 260
    group:insert(dpad_left)
    dpad_left:addEventListener("touch", onDpadLeftTouch)

dpad_right = display.newImageRect("images/dpad/right.png", 78/2, 78/2)
    dpad_right.x = 100
    dpad_right.y = 260
    group:insert(dpad_right)
    dpad_right:addEventListener("touch", onDpadRightTouch)

laser_button = display.newImageRect("images/dpad/laser.png", 78/2, 78/2)
    laser_button.x = 430
    laser_button.y = 260
    group:insert(laser_button)
    laser_button:addEventListener("touch", onLaserButtonTouch)
```

Comment: Your description is hard to follow, so I have reformatted to show how it comes across, please take a look. Assuming it is, then you have too many things in your question: tackle each piece one at a time. Like, first get requirement 1 working, then 2, then 3, then 4. Don't start on 2 until 1 works. You'll probably find that you only have 1 of those four items left to ask on SO, then you can simplify your question dramatically and you'll get more useful help (James' answer is a valiant effort but it's hard to tell if it addresses all 4 items, again, just too much).

Comment: Hello, thank you for helping me, so i sat down yesterday and fixed all 4 problems. Thank you for telling me that i should solve it piece by piece. I think it saved me some time :D. Now i have only one problem and then i have everything solved. And the problem is added in list and its number 5. Everything else works how i wanted it to work. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Great to hear, that's better than what I expected. I made it into an answer.

Comment: Yeah now remains only the 5th problem. :/ Do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand your left and right D-pad touch events don't require dragging of any sort. In which case, there is no need for the "moved" phase of the event. You simply need to check for began and ended. Thinking about it, your the button "isPressed" once the user's finger begins the touch event.

```
function onDpadLeftTouch(event)
    -- body
    if event.phase=='began' then
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(event.target)
        isPressed = true
        if tmr_hold ~= nil then timer.cancel(tmr_hold) end
        tmr_hold = timer.performWithDelay( 8, holdingLeft, 0)
    elseif event.phase == "ended" then
        isPressed = false
        timer.cancel(tmr_hold)
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(nil)
    end
end

function onDpadRightTouch(event)
    -- body
    if event.phase=='began' then
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(event.target)
        isPressed = true
        if tmr_hold ~= nil then timer.cancel(tmr_hold) end
        tmr_hold = timer.performWithDelay( 8, holdingRight, 0)
    elseif event.phase=='ended' then
        isPressed = false
        timer.cancel(tmr_hold)
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(nil)
    end
end
```

Disclaimer: I've not worked with `getCurrentStage()` in Corona, so I don't know if this will have knock-on effects. Also (this shouldn't be an issue, but watch for it in case the event never ends) you *might* have to cancel the event if the user drags their finger off the button  to a different part of the screen before lifting. This would simply be a case of adding the check to the moved phase of each button's event (which you would put back in the same place obviously). Example (assuming central anchors/reference points):

```
elseif event.phase == "moved" then
    if(event.x > (dpad_left.x + (dpad_left.contentWidth/2))) or (event.x < (dpad_left.x - (dpad_left.contentWidth/2))) or (event.y > (dpad_left.y + (dpad_left.contentHeight/2))) or (event.y < (dpad_left.y - (dpad_left.contentHeight/2))) then 
        isPressed = false
        timer.cancel(tmr_hold)
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(nil)
    end
elseif event.phase == "ended" or event.phase == "cancelled" then
    --etc...
```

May look a bit messy, but it'd get the job done.

EDIT: For completeness it's also advised to check for both "ended" and "cancelled" on the 'up' part of the touch event, as "cancelled" handles any case where the system cancels your touch event without you requesting so. So in place of:

```
elseif event.phase == "ended" then
```

use:

```
elseif event.phase == "ended" or event.phase == "cancelled" then
```

Comment: Oh hey, thank you for answering. But when i move my finger, the timer doesnt cancel

Comment: Add a print to the beginning of the timer.cancel event so you can see it is actually called.

If it's not, then add a print to the moved section which prints the bounds of the dpad object (dpad_left or dpad_right) and the event's position (x & y). You'll get a lot of prints from doing this when you move your finger, but it will tell you you which values are being checked, which should let you know why the timer.cancel event is not being called

Comment: Thank you for helping, now i have only one problem :) Its the number 5, if you would know i would be really thankful

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response, but if you haven't solved it already check that one of the touch events is not modifying the object which is rotating in a way that will cancel the rotate event

Answer (score 0):

Your description was hard to follow, so I reformatted to show how it comes across, please take a look.

Assuming I guessed correctly, then you have too many things in your question: tackle each piece one at a time. Like, first get requirement 1 working, then 2, then 3, then 4. Don't start on 2 until 1 works. You might find it all works and no need for SO! Otherwise, you'll know more specifically and you so you can simplify your question dramatically and you'll get more useful help.

UPDATE: now that you have solved all 4 (way to go!), your new item (#5):

My guess is that as soon as you touch the shoot, the touch event from dpad ends, which turns off the timer for holdingLeft/Right. You probably can get this to work with [multitouch](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/events/touchMultitouch/index.html): you'll check the event.id in the handler and you'll be able to ignore it shoot touch so your rotate will continue.

Answer (score 0):

You want to shoot an object while the object is rotating, then you need to define two different event. ex: touch event for rotating the object and tap event for shooting the object..